# laravel how to send email on new user registration only to admin email

Tags: laravel, email

I need to send a notification email only to admin when new user is registered.

When i submitting registration getting error -

Class 'app\Mail\NewUser' not found
in RegisterController.php (line 88)

Here is controller:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    use App\User;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
    use app\Mail\NewUser;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

    protected function create(array $data)
{


    $user = User::create([
        'companyname' => $data['companyname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'VAT' => $data['VAT'],
        'companyphone' => $data['companyphone'],
        'companystreet' => $data['companystreet'],
        'companycity' => $data['companycity'],
        'companycountry' => $data['companycountry'],
        'companypostcode' => $data['companypostcode']

    ]);

    Mail::to('example@gmail.com')->send(new NewUser());

    return $user;
}
```

would be great if someone help me.

Comment: Can you show the code for `app\Mail\NewUser`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you may not have created `NewUser` mailable class. You can create mailable classes by following artisan command.

```
php artisan make:mail NewUser
```

To know how to configure mali parameters like sender, from, to, subject, body etc., refer [Writing Mailable here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#writing-mailables)

#### [Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#generating-mailables)

### Update:

If you have created mailable and not able to find it, most probably it's composer issue. Fire following commands to clear cache and autoload files.

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:cache
```